# Pivot Table Value instead of summarizing

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, pivot-table

I have two tables, one being party details, second being order details of that party. I have defined relationship between two tables being party name in common. Now I want to see party name, dispatch details, and order details in one table.

I have attached image for reference. What I want is to show values of the order details table instead of summarizing.

[image]

I tried google sheets, didn't work. I need to create a report.

Comment: Go with index() and match() - you have the common item between the tables.

Comment: Looks like, when you created the relationship, you chose the Status table as the first table. As such, the Order Details table is filtering the Status table, though you require the contrary. Delete your current relationship and redefine it, choosing the Order Details table as the first table: if done properly, you should see that the *Filter Direction* states <<To Order Details Table.